# C++ move dll files from root to sub folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, components

I'm making a program in visual c++. The program relies on some dll files, which I don't want to place in system32. Now the dll files is in the same folder as my .exe, but i would like to move them to a sub folder. The problem is, if I move the files, my application fails to start and comes with this error message:

---

MyProgram.exe - Unable to Locate Component

This application has failed to start because myDll.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem.

---

I have had the same problem before, where if found a solution, which included adding something to the registry, but i forgot how it worked, and now I can't find the guide again.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: it sounds fishy that you *need* to place dlls in a subdir. mind giving the reason why?

Comment: I don't need to place the dll files in a sub folder, I just don't like to have them in the same folder as my program, because having about 15-20 dll files in the program folder looks messy in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the article you are looking for:

http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/dll/article.php/c99

> Each application can now store it own path the registry under the following key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
>
> The use the application path, set a key for your application, using ONE.EXE from the example above:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ONE.exe
>
> Set the (Default) value to the full path of your executable, for example:
>
> C:\Program Files\ONE\ONE.exe
>
> Add a sub-key named Path

Comment: Correct, that is the article. Thanks, I have used a half day of searching without finding it !

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to solve this problem. As other mentioned you can modify search path for your application in registry.  Sometimes, you don't have rights to write to the registry, or you cannot do it for other reasons, then you can set dll path explicitly, the WinAPI function for that is `SetDllDirectory`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Calling SetDllDirectory obviously requires the process to be running. This means DLLs that are implictly linked can't be in wierd paths using this method.

Comment: I have been looking a bit on this function, but if I understood it correct, this function only works with dll files which is delay loaded, and mine aren't

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths** key. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for complete information. In short, a string called **Path** points to a DLL search path. For example if your application was called "MyApp" a .reg file like this would do the trick:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppPaths\MyApp.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\MyApp\\DLLs"
```