# Libgit2sharp can't find git2-*.dll when built in Xamarin studio on Windows

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin-studio, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm attempting to build a C# desktop application on Windows with Xamarin Studio. After importing the LibGit2Sharp package (and consequently the LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries package), any attempt to actually use the library results in one of these:

```
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: git2-785d8c4
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods:git_config_find_xdg (LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.GitBuf)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.ConvertPath (System.Func`2 pathRetriever) [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_config_find_xdg () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Configuration..ctor (LibGit2Sharp.Repository repository, System.String repositoryConfigurationFileLocation, System.String globalConfigurationFileLocation, System.String xdgConfigurationFileLocation, System.String systemConfigurationFileLocation) [0x00032] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Configuration.BuildFrom (System.String repositoryConfigurationFileLocation, System.String globalConfigurationFileLocation, System.String xdgConfigurationFileLocation, System.String systemConfigurationFileLocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Configuration.BuildFrom (System.String repositoryConfigurationFileLocation, System.String globalConfigurationFileLocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at bravura.tools.git.helper.operations.CoreSettings.run () [0x00015] in C:\code\bravura\git-helper\operations\CoreSettings.cs:37 
  at bravura.tools.git.helper.operations.CoreMenu.OnButtonOkReleased (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00020] in C:\code\bravura\git-helper\operations\CoreMenu.cs:43 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in C:\j\workspace\v\repos\mono\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection\MonoMethod.cs:295
```

I've found that manually putting the dll and pdb in the root output directory sorts out the issue, but that doesn't make for a good build process. Really, there should be a way to add the "NativeBinaries*" directory to the load path. I've already attempted to load the library manually, but since it's not .NET, that option just doesn't work.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this a common issue that I'm just blundering around on?

I've already checked the following issues to no avail:

- [LibGit2Sharp fails to find git2.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15645234/41223)
- [How to use Libgit2Sharp on Mono/MacOsX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27996149/41223)
- [DllNotFoundException and PATH environment variable](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2266)

Comment: If you do not want the git2-785d8c4.dll to be in the same directory as you .exe you will probably have to use [SetDllDirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958742/c-move-dll-files-from-root-to-sub-folder/4960063#4960063) and specify its location.

Comment: Couldn't find the namespace for that function, but while searching, I found a fix that seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around a bit, and a helpful point in the right direction by [Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268874/matt-ward), I found a working answer while reading [Loading dlls from path specified in SetdllDirectory in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410940/41223), or more specifically, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418341/41223).

```
string newPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") +
    ";" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\NativeBinaries\\x86\\";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", newPath);
```